# Movie colors are off on ubuntu

Tags: video, ubuntu-9.10, hdvideo

I've been playing with a new SLR that also happens to record movies.

When I try to view a movie using Movie Player, it plays fine, and the sound is there, but the colors are off - green grass is purple, and my golden retriever is a blue retriever. VLC reports that the file is broken, offers to repair it, and plays it with the same problem.

The same file plays fine under WinXP with both Media Player and Quicktime, and with no problems under MacOS also with Quicktime.

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you use play it on Windows using VLC, does VLC still report it as broken or does it play fine?

Comment: On windows, VLC still reports the file as broken, but "fixes" it and plays properly, with correct colors.

Answer (score 0):

While the file may play fine under windows and quicktime, it is likely that if there is any damage they are just repairing the damage on the fly or somehow getting past it.

I would suggest getting another video file and check whether it is the video or the player/OS.

Comment: It's something with the format.  I downloaded a sample video from the pentax site, and it has the same issues, so it's not a corrupt file.

Comment: Then you should report the bug to Movie Player, it seems like their problem.

Answer (score 0):

open Movie Player , Edit>Prefs>Display>Hue (move the slider to either end)
(not in the middle as is default)

Comment: This solved the problem for me, except that hue slider position is the exact oposite. I'm pretty sure that the hue slider is on the left per default.
In my case colors are OK when I move the hue slider to the middle.

Comment: That didn't change anything, unfortunately.